# Why is my html loaded with ajax reporting the wrong element sizes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have the following code to insert HTML into a div:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "actions.php",
        cache: false
    }).done(function(html) {
        $("#edit").fadeOut('fast', function() {
            $("#edit").empty();
            $("#edit").html(html);
            $("#edit").fadeIn('fast');
        });
    });
```

Inside that html is a div with id "viewport", as well as a script that is supposed to run in the `$("#viewport").ready()` event, and it does, but it seems to run before the layout has adjusted to the css.  When I output the width and height of the div, it says `100,100`.  Underneath that div (not inside it) is an `<img>`.  If I make the script run when the image is done loading (takes a few seconds), then it outputs the right size and everything is good.  The problem is I cannot wait for the image to load before running that code.  Does anyone know why the code is running before the elements have taken the sizes that they are supposed to?  Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You don't need to call `.empty()` before `.html()`, since the latter replaces everything.

Comment: If the sizes are dependent on the image, how can they take the size before the image is loaded?

Comment: The sizes are not dependent on the image, the image is just another element in the html, but it doesn't change the viewport div's size.  I brought up the image because it takes a few seconds longer to load, so when you run the code when the image loads, the viewport's size is fine.

Comment: @Zach Unless you know the width and height upfront (and it seems you do not) there is no other way than to subscribe to the load event of the img and wait for the image to be loaded before continuing.

Comment: have the server put image size attributes on the `<img>` tag. Also, no point using `ready` with ajax... ready is completed during inital page load... ready handlers have no affect afterwards

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this on my own.  I used `.load()` to load the elements directly into the div instead of `.ajax()`.  This seems to allow all of the elements take shape inside the div properly.